# Network capture toolset that store a buffer and saves on a trigger

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireshark, tcpdump

Is there a simple tool or utility I can use to buffer a network capture for say the last 3 minutes and if an event happens perhaps by a GPIO trigger or UDP message I write the last 3 minutes and the following 1 minute to disk? We have a network freeze that occurs between 40 minutes and 14 hours and I'd like to capture network traffic around the detected event time to better understand the situation. I have used tcpdump and wireshark in the past before but have always manually triggered the start and stop of the captures and I need the stop time to be automated and want to avoid recording a bunch of irrelevant data. Most of our development environments are using Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters.

At this point we're not limited to any language or building the tool from scratch if needed.

Comment: Stack Overflow focuses on programming while [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) focuses on networking and server administration. This can be a good question for Stack Overflow if you can [provide](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58442622/edit) a code snippet of what you have so far.

Comment: @RossJacobs, This is to identify a potential programming error or defect in a software product. I figure it is valid because it might make sense to use a few bash commands or scripts to get the network captures I need.

Comment: @simingeer To be clear, I think that this is a good question in essence and mostly in content. Questions should have code (and this is applicable here) see 2nd sentence of [Asking Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Secondly, this question as stated is also too broad - it does not specify which language you are looking for a solution in (though bash is a good guess here). Thirdly, adding a code snippet (even if you have a "<solution goes here>") demonstrates effort, which often removes ambiguity in the question (and makes it easier to answer).

Comment: In short, make your question more specific and easier to follow for both responder and future readers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try running a script that launches 2 instances of [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html), one to capture all traffic into a ring buffer of limited duration and files, and the other instance to merely wait for the capture event in question.  Once the capture event occurs, the 2nd instance of `dumpcap` could terminate, sleep for 1 minute, and then the remaining `dumpcap` instance could be killed.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting capture instance ..."
dumpcap -i eth0 -f "TBD Capture Filter" -b duration:180 -b files:2 -w file.pcapng &
echo "Starting event instance ..."
dumpcap -i eth0 -f "TBD Event Capture Filter" -c 1
echo "Got event; sleeping for 60 seconds ..."
sleep 60
echo "Killing all dumpcap instances ..."
killall dumpcap
echo "Done."
```

When capturing has finished, you should be left with up to 2 files containing the last 6 minutes (maximum) of data.  You can even add a [`mergecap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html) command to the script to merge the 2 files together if you wish: `mergecap -F pcapng file.pcapng file_*.pcapng`.

And in case the 2nd `dumpcap` instance leaves behind its temporary capture file, you can clean that up as well if you wish, e.g., `rm -f /tmp/wireshark*`